# Print from Ubuntu (or Peppermint) to Windows printer

Tags: printing, samba, pdf

I am a newbie to Ubuntu after many years with Microsoft.  I have configured my Dell 1320C laser printer to operate under MS Windows 7 including double sided prints. For the Ubuntu machine I can only find drivers for DPC525 printer. This does not appear to support double sided printed prints.

I can create pdf files of the document to be printed and then get the Windows machine to print double sided. Is there a (simple) way of printing the document via the Windows machine without converting to pdf first?  I have heard about SAMBA and CUPS but do not really understand them.

Comment: Is the printer shared from the Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

The CUPS administrative interface is available at http://localhost:631.

Click on `Administration`, then on `Manage Printers`. Select your printer, then from the `Administration` list, select `Set Default Options`. This will get you to a screen where you can select `Double-Sided Printing`.